# Memory leak in .Net Speech.Synthesizer?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, sapi, speech-synthesis

I found a continuous leakage in my application. After examining using a memory profiler, I found the course is some object from Microsoft Speech.Synthesizer

So I build up a toy project to verify the hypothesis:

//Toy example to show memory leak in  Speech.Synthesizer object

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "hello world. This is a long sentence";
    PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
    pb.StartStyle(new PromptStyle(PromptRate.ExtraFast));
    pb.AppendText(text);
    pb.EndStyle();
    SpeechSynthesizer tts = new SpeechSynthesizer();

while (true)
{
    //SpeechSynthesizer tts = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    Console.WriteLine("Speaking..."); 
    tts.Speak(pb);

    //Print private working set sieze
    Console.WriteLine("Memory: {0} KB\n", (Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024).ToString("0"));

    //tts.Dispose();    //also this doesn't work as well
    //tts = null;

    GC.Collect();   //a little help, but still leaks
}
}
```

And the result actually confirmed the memory leak is from Speech.Synthesizer

```
Speaking...
```

Memory: 42184 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 42312 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 42440 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 42568 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 42696 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 42824 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 43016 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 43372 KB

I googled it and found many others have come across the same problem:
1:
[Constant Memory Leak in SpeechSynthesizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204012/constant-memory-leak-in-speechsynthesizer)
2:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664196/system-speech-has-a-memory-leak

but sadly I didn't find any solution to it. Since its a problem already asked long time ago, so I want to ask if its been solved or not?

Many Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Seems like while I switch to use SAPI COM dll rather than .Net Speech.Synthesizer package (although essentially they are the same thing), the memory stops leaking.

***Why is the two invoke behavior (SAPI dll vs .net Speech package) have different memory behavior? As the latter seems is just a wrapper to the former SAPI dll.***

```
    static void Test2()
{
    //SAPI COM component this time
    SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass tts = new SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass();
    tts.SetRate(5);
    string text = "hello world. This is a long sentence";
    //tts.Speak("helloWorld", SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
while (true)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Speaking...");
    tts.Speak(text, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);

    //Print private working set sieze
    Console.WriteLine("Memory: {0} KB\n", (Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024).ToString("0"));

    GC.Collect();
}
```

}

Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Speaking...
Memory: 32044 KB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final solution:

Google-ing relevant keywords telling me that it's actually a bug from Microsoft.

Seems like while I switch to use SAPI COM dll rather than .Net Speech.Synthesizer package (although essentially they are the same thing), the memory stops leaking.

Comment: Can you post any of those links? Is there an MS Connect issue for it?

Comment: @codekaizen Yes, actually I read some users report in MS forum, the post is posted two years ago. That 's why I reach such conclusion. I will need to search again for the post I actually read last month...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure all the details on the SpeechSynthesizer, but you could try using the disposable pattern here. Since SpeechSynthesizer implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

Your code would look like the following:

```
while (true)
{
   using (SpeechSynthesizer tts = new SpeechSynthesizer())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Speaking..."); 
      tts.Speak(pb);

      //Print private working set sieze
      Console.WriteLine("Memory: {0} KB\n",(Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 / 1024).ToString("0"));
   }
}
```

If you notice this is very similar to Microsoft's example [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx)

This looks to in fact be a memory leak, Have you tried using the [Microsoft.Speech runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14373)?
The syntax looks very similar and they have mentioned it *shouldn't* have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you:) but it still has the memory leaks

Comment: It does look then based on Microsoft's own admission this leaks. See Edit above.

Comment: Why is the two invoke behavior (SAPI dll vs .net Speech package) have different memory behavior? As the latter seems is just a wrapper to the former SAPI dll.

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm going off of what a Microsoft representative said here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/664196/system-speech-has-a-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old thread, but there is another solution for the problem.
Use **Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer** instead of **System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer**.

Microsoft.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer is included in the *Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK) (Version 11)* - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

This version of the Synthesizer does not have the memory leak.