# Can C# SAPI speak SSML string?

Tags: c#, speech, sapi, text-to-speech, ssml

I implemented a TTS in my C# WPF project.

Previously, I use the TTS in System.Speech.Synthesis namespace to speak. The speaking content is in SSML format (Speech Synthesizer Markup Language, support customize the speaking rate, voice, emphasize) like following:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US"><prosody rate="x-fast">hello world. This is a long sentence speaking very fast!</prosody></speak>
```

But unfortunately the System.Speech.Synthesis TTS has a memory leak problem, as I mentioned in question [Memory leak in .Net Speech.Synthesizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707187/memory-leak-in-net-speech-synthesizer).

So I decide to use SAPI COM component. I can easily let SAPI to speak plain text content. But then I continue to try letting it speak SSML string, I failed. The code is like following:

```
//Initialize TTS instance

SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass tts = new SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass();

//Generate SSML string

string textToSpeak = "hello world speak Extra Fast.";
PromptBuilder pb = new PromptBuilder();
pb.StartStyle(new PromptStyle(PromptRate.ExtraFast));
pb.AppendText(textToSpeak);
pb.EndStyle();

ssmlString = pb.ToXml();    //ssmlString = @"<speak version=""1.0"" .... 

//Speak!

tts.Speak(ssmlString, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFParseSsml);
```

The essential part of the code is

```
tts.Speak(ssmlString, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFParseSsml);
```

Which uses the [SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to specify the TTS speaking behavior. I have tried several combinations of the flags, but none of them successfully speak out the SSML content.

Particularly, the above code will also raise following exceptions:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   Message="Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045003"
>   Source="Interop.SpeechLib"   ErrorCode=-2147201021   StackTrace:
>          at SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass.Speak(String Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags)
>          at SpeechSynthesisMemLeakTest.Program.Test2() in D:\Proj\TestSolutions\CSharp_Quick_Apps\SpeechSynthesisMemLeakTest\Program.cs:line
>   60
>          at SpeechSynthesisMemLeakTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Proj\TestSolutions\CSharp_Quick_Apps\SpeechSynthesisMemLeakTest\Program.cs:line
>   17
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Could anyone tell me how to correctly use the flag to speak out SSML content?

Answer (score 3):

What TTS engine/voice are you using?   The Microsoft TTS engines definitely support SSML using the code that you're using; however, other voices/engines may not support SSML.

Error 0x80045003 is SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT (The caller has specified an unsupported format), which leads me to believe that you need to use a different TTS engine (that supports SSML).

Answer (score 0):

Use this flag instead

```
tts.Speak(ssmlString, SpeechLib.SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFIsXML);
```

Tested using

> - SpeechLib 5.4
> - C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Speech.dll